# If the Wronskian W of $f$ and $g$ is $3e^{4t}$, and if $f(t) = e^{2t}$ how may I find $g(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

I'm struggling with a seemingly simple problem in differential equations.

> If the Wronskian W of $f$ and $g$ is $3e^{4t}$, and if $f(t) = e^{2t}$, find $g(t)$.

So from that I made a first order linear differential equation that is $$g'(t)-2g(t)=3e^{4t}$$
then I proceeded to solve by using an integrating factor which is $$e^{-2t}$$ and what i got was $$ g(t)=\frac{3}{2}(e^{4t})+Ce^{2t}$$
but this is not the real answer according to my text book which says it is 
$$g(t) = te^{2t} + ce^{2t}$$ 
so my question is where am i going wrong? I don't understand where the $t$ came from in $$te^{2t}$$
any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: The Wronskian of f and g will be $e^{2t}g'(t)-2e^{2t}g(t)=3e^{4t}$.  When you divided out by $e^{2t}$, you forgot to divide the right hand side.  This likely explains the the error (as the rest of the work looks fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your very first step, you forgot to divide $3e^{4t}$ by $e^{2t}$ as well.  From the information given, you have:
$$e^{2t}g'-2e^{2t}g=3e^{4t}$$
So dividing by $e^{2t}$ gives us the ODE
$$g'-2g=3e^{2t}$$
The solution to this is as the book states.

Comment: oh my gosh thank you. it sometimes takes a second set of eyes to catch something so simple as that. thank you soooooo much for that.

Answer (score 1):

You know that
$$W(f,g) = \left|\begin{array}{cc}
f & g\\
f' & g'
\end{array}\right| = \left|\begin{array}{cc}
e^{2t} &g\\
2e^{2t} & g'
\end{array}\right| = e^{2t}g' - 2e^{2t}g  = 3e^{4t}.$$

If you simplify by factoring out $e^{2t}$ and cancelling, that would give you
$$g' - 2g = 3e^{2t},$$
instead of $g'-2g = 3e^{4t}$, which is what you had. So it looks like you made a simplification error.

Will this give you the correct answer?

Comment: thank you so much for you answer! :) this has been so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is abosoltely correct
After the determinant your equation becomes
g'-2g=3e²t
Integrating factor becomes
I.F.=e-²t
Multiplying both sides by I.F.
Clearly you will get
g×I.F.=$3t +c
Now g=($3t+c)/I.F.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).